# Why this isn't printing out the X,Y np arrays

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a dataframe `activities_and_attractions` with X,Y attributes numbers. I want to create a numpy array

[[x1,y1]

[x2,y2]

[x3,y3]]

but it turns out it only prints the last row

```
data = np.array([activities_and_attractions.X[0], activities_and_attractions.Y[0]])

for i in range(len(activities_and_attractions.index)):
    np.vstack((data, np.array([activities_and_attractions.X[i], activities_and_attractions.Y[i]])))

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the output of `vstack` to `data` in the loop:

```
for i in range(len(activities_and_attractions.index)):
    data = np.vstack((data, np.array([activities_and_attractions.X[i], activities_and_attractions.Y[i]])))  # assign to data
```

Consider using [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) for this task. It is not efficient to grow ndarrays in this fashion.

What's wrong with:

```
data = np.array( (activities_and_attractions.X, activities_and_attractions.Y) )
```